# MySQL left outer join the same table multiple times?

Tags: mysql, max, left-join, multiple-instances

So I have a **MySQL** dilemma which seemed to be relatively simple, however not the case.

I have two tables: one which holds a list of unique ids to display and another table which lists the ids next to a timestamp.

```
======   ============================
| ID |   | ID |      Timestamp      |
======   ============================
| 1  |   | 1  | 2015-10-10 00:00:00 |
| 2  |   | 1  | 2015-10-10 00:10:00 |
| .. |   | 2  | 2015-10-10 00:00:00 |
======   ============================
```

I need to display a boolean if the relevant id has records in *Table B* **between two Date-Times** and the last date it was active **of all time**.

---

[image: Visual Digram]

---

I have tried something similar to this:

```
SELECT 
    a.`ID`, 
    MAX(b1.`Timestamp`) IS NOT NULL as 'Active',
    MAX(b2.`Timestamp`) AS 'LastActive'
FROM `Table-A` a
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Table-B` b1
    ON a.ID = b1.ID
    AND b1.`Timestamp` BETWEEN @startTime AND @endTime
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Table-B` b2
    ON a.ID = b2.ID
GROUP BY a.ID
;
```

Currently not sure why: but the query seems to run infinitely and not get any results. Can anyone suggest the correct way to get the results needed in my query?

---

## EDIT:

Here is an `EXPLAIN SELECT` for the above query.

[image: EXPLAIN SELECT]

Comment: i've refined the query a bit, please try the updated one

Comment: Can you add results of [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) for your query? it may be you miss an index over b.ID or better (ID, Timestamp). Left joining the same table twice should work otherwise.

Comment: @jkavalik Added an `EXPLAIN` for you

Comment: @ChiMo how many rows are in table-a? And is there an index over ID? Do these tables contain any other columns? You should probably add index on `a.ID` and other one - multicolumn on `b` with `(ID, Timestamp)`. The first one should get rid of `Using temporary; Using filesort`, and the second might optimize the max() - but I am not sure about that, may depend on your server version and some optimizer decisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
SELECT 
    a.*, 
    IF(b1.cnt IS NULL, FALSE, TRUE) AS is_found, 
    IFNULL(b2.dt, '-') AS max_dt 
FROM table1 a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            id, 
            COUNT(*) AS cnt 
        FROM table2 
        WHERE 
            `timestamp` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31' 
        GROUP BY 1) b1 
    ON a.id=b1.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT id, 
            MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS dt 
        FROM table2 
        GROUP BY 1) b2 
    ON a.id=b2.id
```

Comment: this still seems to not show the last date of all time - the WHERE statement inside the LEFT OUTER JOIN cuts out the results before the 'MAX(timestamp) => dt' is calculated.

Comment: true, it was done intentionally to get max(date) from within the given date range. If you want to validate in given date range and need max date from outside of this range, then use this query `SELECT a.*, IF(b1.cnt IS NULL, FALSE, TRUE) AS is_found, IFNULL(b2.dt, '-') AS max_dt FROM table1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table2 WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31' GROUP BY 1) b1 ON a.id=b1.id LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS dt FROM table2 GROUP BY 1)b2 ON a.id=b2.id`